# How do you conjugate verbs in passive voice in Spanish and how do you make passive infinitives?

Tags: verbos, conjugación, voz-pasiva, infinitivo

I was wondering how I should say the following sentence?

> This will help it **be seen** on more news feeds
>   Esto lo ayudará ........

But out of curiosity I decided to generalize my question. [Spanish Dict](http://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/ver) suggests the [linked](http://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/ver) conjugation for the verb `to see = ver`.
Corresponding to each active conjugation we should have its passive (if it's like English). For example:

---

I see ---> I am seen by
I saw ----> I was seen by
I used to see ----> I used to be seen
I would see ----> I would be seen by
I will see ----> I will be seen by
I have seen ----> I have been seen by
I had seen ----> I had been seen by
I would have seen ----> I would have been seen by
I will have seen ----> I will have been seen by
to see ----> to be seen

---

Then which structure does the role of the structure **to be** + past participle in Spanish?
Or how is the passive voice and so the passive infinitive made in Spanish?
How is the passive voice conjugated?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks suspiciously like link s[am for a spanish dictionary site. Question body full of google-juicy keywords.

Sospecho de linkspam. demasiada palabras googlejugosas n.n

Comment: @hlecuanda el usuario tienen buena reputación en otros stacks y un perfil completo. Voto por dejarla abierta. Le puede servir a alguien.

Answer (score 5):

You don't really want us to fill in all your conjugations, do you?

Passive in Spanish is similar to English. Just conjugate the `ser` verb and add the participle *visto* (or *vistos* if plural, or *vista*/*vistas* if feminine). For example: *yo veo -> yo soy visto*; *nosotros hubiéramos visto -> nosotros hubiéramos sido vistos*.

Beware! In *nosotros hubiéramos sido vistos*, the *sido* part is invariant, while the *vistos* is in concordance with the passive subject *nosotros*.

But Spanish speakers prefer the reflexive passive: *yo soy visto -> se me ve*; *nosotros hubiéramos sido vistos -> se nos hubiera visto*, that is somewhat easier. That way, your original phrase would be:

> Esto ayudará a que se vea en más *feeds* de noticias.

About your difficult conjugations, actually nothing special:

- Infinitive: *ver -> ser visto*, reflexive passive would be *verse*.
- Imperative *ve -> sé visto* ; *ved -> sed vistos*. Reflexive would be constructed similar to the third person imperative, with the present subjuntive and beginning with *Que*: *Que se te vea*.